# The best way of creating a simple voting system

Tags: database, client-side, server-side

I want to create a simple voting system, where people can vote for a candidate and the the votes for each candidate gets displayed on the website dynamically.

I am a front-end developer and do not really get to work with server side code too often, so I am unsure how to approach this.

Is the best way to use a server-side language (like php) and SQL? Or can this be done with HTML5/Javascript/jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have told that you are front end developer this is not enough to create a dynamic **Simple voting system**
Before coding your application you need decide it's architecture

- 3-tier
- MVC

both the architectures involves 3 different components

1. front end (html/css/javascript/JQUERY everything render by browser )
2. Server Side (PHP/JAVA/RUBY)
3. DATABASE end (MYSQL /MS-SQL using SQL as language)

so you need to cover server side and database side as well in order to develop a dynamic system.You can use [Ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) as well in order to improve your system
In short you need persistence storage as well so server side will take your front end (user data) to a persistence storage like(databases)

Comment: the difference between 3-tier and MVC is realization (integration) between components (front/server/database end)

Comment: thank you very much, appriate your answer. If the system needs to be comapitble with Delphi, what do I need to use? Can I use the following then-  html/javascript(client), Delphi(Server) and MySQL/MS SQL?

Comment: well i won't recommend you Delphi as a server side language. because of many reasons like there is no great support of it you can use    php(very easy to learn) and has a lot of support ([tutorials] (http://www.w3schools.com/php/) ) available

Comment: but is it possible to use delphi alongside MySQL?

Comment: yes this is possible to use delphi along side MYSQL this post might be helpfull for you [MySql and Delphi direct connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8369597/mysql-and-delphi-direct-connection)